# Include elements from a List() in other List() with criteria

Tags: r

I run regressions with these variables pairs:

```
regression_pairs=c("A~B", "C~D", "E~F", "G~H","I~J","K~L","M~N","O~P","Q~R")

regression_pairs
```

And stored the residulas in a list `residuals.new`:

```
residuals.new <- list()
 a=c(1,2,3,4,5)
 b=c(6,7,8,9,10)
 c=c(11,12,13,14,15)
 d=c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
 e=c(21,22,23,24,25)
 f=c(26,27,28,29,30)
 g=c(31,32,33,34,35)
 h=c(36,37,38,39,40)
 i=c(41,42,43,44,45)

 residuals.new[[1]]=a
 residuals.new[[2]]=b
 residuals.new[[3]]=c
 residuals.new[[4]]=d
 residuals.new[[5]]=e
residuals.new[[6]]=f
residuals.new[[7]]=g
residuals.new[[8]]=h
residuals.new[[9]]=i

residuals.new
```

So, the residuals from regression `A~B` are `1,2,3,4,5` , the residuals from regression C~D are `6,7,8,9,10` and so on.

After some criteria I got the best pairs:

```
bestresults<-list()

best_pairs=c("A~B", "G~H", "Q~R")
```

Now I need to figure out a way to create a list `best.residuals` relating the best pairs with its own residuals.

What function I could use? Any sugestion?

So My output List would be:

```
the.bestresiduals<-list()

 the.bestresiduals[[1]]=c(1,2,3,4,5)
 the.bestresiduals[[2]]=c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
 the.bestresiduals[[3]]=c(41,42,43,44,45)

the.bestresiduals

    [[1]]
    [1] 1 2 3 4 5

    [[2]]
    [1] 16 17 18 19 20

    [[3]]
    [1] 41 42 43 44 45
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There are nine regression pairs while the residual list has only 8 elements

Comment: `setNames(mget(letters[1:9]),regression_pairs)[best_pairs]` should solve your problem

Comment: `setNames(residuals.new,regression_pairs)[best_pairs]`